# Shopping Cart Update Total Function doesnt work

Tags: javascript, html, e-commerce, shopping-cart

I am building an eCommerce store website, and I am facing an issue. The function `updateCartTotal` doesn't work at all. The script is also added to the bottom of the HTML body.

Thanks in advance.

HTML:

```
<span class="material-symbols-outlined" id="cart-icon">
shopping_cart
</span>
<div class="cart">
  <h2 class="cart-title">Your Shopping Cart</h2>
  <div class="cart-content">
    <div class="cart-box">
      <img src="/Monn-Homme/images/tie1.jpg" class="cart-image">
      <div class="detail-box">
        <div class="cart-product-title">
          Tie
        </div>
        <div class="cart-price"> £10.99</div>
        <input type="number" value="1" class="cart-qty">
      </div>
      <span class="material-symbols-outlined" id="cart-remove">
      delete
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="total">
    <div class="total-title">Total</div>
    <div class="total-price">£10.99</div>
  </div>
  <button type="button" class="buy-btn">Buy Now</button>
  <span class="material-symbols-outlined" id="close-cart">
  close
  </span>
</div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
let cartIcon = document.getElementById("cart-icon");
let cart = document.querySelector(".cart");
let CloseCart = document.querySelector("#close-cart");

cartIcon.onclick = () => {
  cart.classList.add("active");
};

CloseCart.onclick = () => {
  cart.classList.remove("active");
};

if (document.readyState == "loading") {
  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", ready);
} else {
  ready();
}


function ready() {
  var removeCartButtons = document.getElementsByClassName("material-symbols-outlined");

  for (var i = 0; i < removeCartButtons.length; i++) {
    var button = removeCartButtons[i];
    button.addEventListener("click", removeCartItem)

  }

  // Quantity Change //

  var quantitInputs = document.getElementsByClassName("cart qty");
  for (var i = 0; i < quantitInputs.length; i++) {
    var input = quantitInputs[i];
    input.addEventListener("change", quantityChanged);
  }
}


function removeCartItem(event) {
  var buttonClicked = event.target;
  buttonClicked.parentElement.remove();
  updateCartTotal();
}

quantityChanged = (event) => {
  var input = event.target;
  if (isNaN(input.value) || input.value <= 0) {
    input.value = 1;
  }

  updateCartTotal();

}



function updateCartTotal() {
  var cartContainer = document.getElementsByClassName("cart-content")[0];
  var cartBox = cartContainer.getElementsByClassName("cart-box");
  var total = 0
  for (var i = 0; i < cartBox.length; i++) {
    var cartBox = cartBox[i]
    var priceElement = cartBox.getElementsByClassName("cart-price")[0]
    var quantityElement = cartBox.getElementsByClassName("cart-qty")[0]
    price = parseFloat(priceElement.innerText.replace("£", ""))
    quantity = quantityElement.value
    total = total + (price * quantity)

  }

  document.getElementsByClassName("total-price")[0].innerText = total


}
```

i am expecting the total to update as the quantity changes, and the function to work

Answer (score 0):

You have the following mistakes-

1. There is no element with the class name `cart qty`.

```
var quantitInputs = document.getElementsByClassName("cart qty");
```

2. `quantityChanged` function should have a `function` keyword.
3. You are using the same name variable cartBox in `updateCartTotal` function which is creating confusion-

```
var cartBox = cartContainer.getElementsByClassName("cart-box");
for (var i = 0; i < cartBox.length; i++) {
    var cartBox = cartBox[i]
}
```

Now, after fixing these mistakes, your code will look like the below which is working.

**Note-** I moved all the declarations to the top and I replaced those two methods-

> getElementsByClassName() = querySelectorAll()
>
> getElementsByClassName()[0] = querySelector()

```js
let cartIcon = document.querySelector("#cart-icon");
let cart = document.querySelector(".cart");
let CloseCart = document.querySelector("#close-cart");
var quantitInputs = document.querySelectorAll(".cart-qty");
var removeCartButtons = document.querySelectorAll(".material-symbols-outlined");
var cartContainer = document.querySelector(".cart-content");
var cartBox = cartContainer.querySelectorAll(".cart-box");
var totalEl = document.querySelector(".total-price")

cartIcon.onclick = () => {
  cart.classList.add("active");
};

CloseCart.onclick = () => {
  cart.classList.remove("active");
};

if (document.readyState == "loading") {
  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", ready);
} else {
  ready();
}

function ready() {
  for (var i = 0; i < removeCartButtons.length; i++) {
    var button = removeCartButtons[i];
    button.addEventListener("click", removeCartItem);
  }
  // Quantity Change //
  for (var i = 0; i < quantitInputs.length; i++) {
    var input = quantitInputs[i];
    input.addEventListener("change", quantityChanged);
  }
}

function removeCartItem(event) {
  var buttonClicked = event.target;
  buttonClicked.parentElement.remove();
  updateCartTotal();
}

function quantityChanged(event) {
  var input = event.target;
  if (isNaN(input.value) || input.value <= 0) {
    input.value = 1;
  }
  updateCartTotal();
};

function updateCartTotal() {
  var total = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < cartBox.length; i++) {
    var cartBoxEl = cartBox[i];
    var priceElement = cartBoxEl.querySelector(".cart-price");
    var quantityElement = cartBoxEl.querySelector(".cart-qty");
    price = parseFloat(priceElement.innerText.replace("£", ""));
    quantity = quantityElement.value;
    total = total + price * quantity;
  }
  if (totalEl) {
    totalEl.innerText = total;
  }
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span class="material-symbols-outlined" id="cart-icon">
  shopping_cart
  </span>
  <div class="cart">
    <h2 class="cart-title">Your Shopping Cart</h2>
    <div class="cart-content">
      <div class="cart-box">
        <img src="/Monn-Homme/images/tie1.jpg" class="cart-image">
        <div class="detail-box">
          <div class="cart-product-title">
            Tie
          </div>
          <div class="cart-price"> £10.99</div>
          <input type="number" value="1" class="cart-qty">
        </div>
        <span class="material-symbols-outlined" id="cart-remove">
        delete
        </span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="total">
      <div class="total-title">Total</div>
      <div class="total-price">£10.99</div>
    </div>
    <button type="button" class="buy-btn">Buy Now</button>
    <span class="material-symbols-outlined" id="close-cart">
    close
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Glad, it worked. You can upvote if you find it useful, and mark it as accepted if it solved your problem.